# set theoretic proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

the question is Show that ∆= if and only if =∅.

since it's a biconditional, I have to prove both directions, where one direction is if ∆=, then =∅. The other direction is if =∅, then ∆=.

the second direction is easy to prove since I only have to substitute =∅ into (\)∪(\) which is the definition of ∆. But I have a hard time proving the first direction. I have an idea of using contrapositive which is if  is not empty, then ∆ is not . There are several possible cases:

1. and  are two disjoint sets.
2. and  overlap a little (I mean not entirely)
3. is a subset of .
4. is a subset of .

to show these 4 cases, I decide to use Venn Diagrams as illustrations, but I'm afraid it wouldn't be formal enough. Can anyone give me some clues on how to prove the first direction?

Comment: If you assume $x \in B \setminus A$, you can get a contradiction. Similarly, if you assume $x \in B \cap A$, you also get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas has given some good hints, heres goes a proof of $(A\Delta B = A \implies B=\emptyset)$.

Assume $A\Delta B=A$.

Let $x\in B$. If so, $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$.

If $x\notin A$, then $x\in A\Delta B$, because $x\in B\setminus A$. But then, $x\in A$. Contradiction.

If $x\in A$, then $x\notin A\Delta B$, because $x\notin A\setminus B$ and $x\notin B\setminus A$. But then, $x\notin A$. Contradiction.

Therefore, there is no $x\in B$ and, by definition, $B=\emptyset$.

Q.E.D.

I hope it's helpful and without any mistakes :)